# Javascript fill different svg shapes at once

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, svg

I'm looking for a solution for filling different svg shapes at once with a single click.

[Code is here](http://jsfiddle.net/obtp73gw/1/)

As you can see, there are two main svg shapes with some sub-shapes. What I want to do is to fill all the sub-shapes of one full-shape when I click only one of the sub-shapes. Every path has it's own ID, which is similar. In example case, it's 1_7-{b,p,d,m,o} and 1_6-{b,p,d,m,o}.

So if I click either b,p,d,m,o of 1_7, I want whole 1_7 turn red.

The only problem (I think) is that I don't know how to substract the info whether I have clicked 1_7 or 1_6 from this.id while the javascript function is executed.

I guess the whole thing would be added to

```
elem.onclick = function() {
```

Comment: maybe give them all a class and fill the class on click?

Comment: The problem is that it's the part of my full project in which there would be different kind of full-shapes and overal 148 sub-shapes...

Comment: It's here http://shrt.edu.pl/beta/teeth/svg6/

Comment: If you target the entire shape instead of the sub shapes you should be fine - so target the svg instead of the path. http://jsfiddle.net/obtp73gw/6/

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest giving them a class or set of classes to identify them and fill all elements that match a selector (like '.1_7' or '.1_6'). Here's a function that could do that:

```
var fillBySelection = function(selector, color) {
    var elems = document.querySelectorAll(selector);
    for(var i=0; i<elems.length; i++) {
        elems[i].style.fill = color;
    }
}
```

If you keep the svg shapes defined as you have them, all siblings, you could fill all the siblings the same color. [Here's a fiddle that does that](http://jsfiddle.net/obtp73gw/5/).

The fillByChildren function would look like this, you'd pass it `this.parentNode` and a css color:

```
var fillChildren = function(element, color) {
    var children = element.children;
    for(var i=0; i<children.length; i++) {
        children[i].style.fill = color;
    }
}
```

Comment: Nicely done. Is there any way to pass which ones of either full-shapes or sub-shapes are collored and in which to some kind of javascript array? I want to pass the info to PHP afterwards.

Comment: you'd probably want to pass a class to set on each element instead of color (`className` instead of `style.fill`) then you can use `document.querySelectorAll` to get all elements with the class and you'd get the bonus of setting the fill color in css.

Comment: Is that a good idea if there are a lot of colors in final version? It's here http://shrt.edu.pl/beta/teeth/svg6/

Comment: Actually you may be right... Thanks for help :)
But if you have any other suggestions, I'm waiting :P

P.S. So it would return the id's which are using specified css class?

Comment: if you have a lot of colors or if color is more than style, then it's probably not a good idea to set it in css. You can always set both the color and the class and do a query on the class. I suppose you could also just query for all paths with a certain color, `document.querySelectorAll('path[style*="rgb(255, 0, 0)"]')` I'm not sure that'd work in ie though

Answer (score 0):

You can transverse the parent node with `parentNode` on `this` and then change the style on the child nodes.

```
var forms = document.getElementsByTagName("path");

for (var a = 0; a < forms.length; a++) {
  var elem = forms[a];
  elem.onclick = function() {
    var nodes = this.parentNode.childNodes

    for(var n in nodes){
     if (nodes[n].tagName ==="path"){
       if (nodes[n].style.fill=='rgb(255, 0, 0)') {
        nodes[n].style.fill = '';
    } else {
        nodes[n].style.fill = 'red';
    }
     }
    }

    return false;
  };
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use silblings for this.
I tried this

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/obtp73gw/1/)
           elem.onclick = function() {

```
        var first = this.parentNode.firstChild;
        var check = this.style.fill=='rgb(255, 0, 0)';
        for ( ; first; first = first.nextSibling ) {
            if ( first.nodeType === 1 ) {
                if (check) {
                first.style.fill = '';
                } else {
                first.style.fill = 'red';
            }
            }
        }
    return false;
  };
```